# How to Instantiate a function from string in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string, which contains the full text of a function:

```
my_str = 'def my_fn(a, b):\n    return a+b'
```

I would like my program to be able to instantiate `my_func`, save it to an object and call it later.

`exec(my_str)` returns a `<function my_fn at ...>` when viewed in the command line, but is `undefined` at runtime. `eval(my_str)` returns a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and isn't really what I want anyway.

I'm confused here. How can I get my function variable from this string?

It would be a nice bonus if I could rename the function to something else later (without knowing its name at first).

*note: I'm aware that using `exec` is dangerous. If there are better ways to do this, I'm open to suggestions. For the moment, this is just a research code. It's run locally, I show people how to use it and it isn't going on the internet.*

Comment: When I use `exec(my_str)`, I can call your function just fine.  Either way, running arbitrary code from strings is almost never something you want to be doing, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @user3483203 It works or me in my terminal with no problem. The issue is that at runtime, after `exec(my_str)`, `my_fn` is still undefined.

(Or was that a joke about being able to execute arbitrary code on my program. You're not wrong :P)

Comment: What do you mean at runtime? I have no problem running your function in a script, in the terminal, etc.

Comment: I'm working on a research program which allows users to pass in a function which modifies their data. As part of this, I need a way of storing that function for later use. 

I'd like to store the function source (which they typed) as part of a JSON string. It's not a very elegant approach, but considering the user is running the program locally on their own data, the risk is acceptable at the moment.

Comment: How do you make sure that your user always gives the right name to the function?

Comment: @FlyingTeller - Just updated the note to make that clear. At the moment, I sit next to the user running it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking to do
`exec(my_str, globals())`
which will put in the globals dictionary allowing you to access it

Comment: @sundance the error is when using `eval`. There is no syntax error when using `exec`

Comment: Well, maybe _not_ `globals()`, but a dictionary you created yourself.  The you can access the function from that dictionary. This way it doesn't matter what the user calls the function: just pick the only function that is there after exec, or complain if there is nothing or more than one function in that dictionary.  Also the user can't accidentally(?) overwrite something existing in `globals()`.